# Base and Dimension of Sum and Section

Tags: linear-algebra

In the context of linear algebra of a computer science student:

I got $2$ subspaces of $\mathbb R^4$
$V = \{(x,y,z,u) ∈ \mathbb R^4 | y+z+u = 0\}$
$W = \{(x,y,z,u) ∈ \mathbb R^4 | x+y=0, z=2u\}$

I found Base and Dimension of
$V: \{(1,0,0,0); (0,-1,1,0); (0,-1,0,1)\}$, Dim = 3

And for $W: \{(-1,1,0,0); (0,0,2,1)\}$

My question now is how do I find the base and dimension for $V+W$ and for $V∩W$
And what is the method to get there?

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for that, I'm new here

Answer (score 1):

For $V+W$, note $W\not\subset V$, so $\dim V+W\ge \dim V+1=4$. As we're in $\mathbf R^4$, this means $V+W=\mathbf R^4$, and  $\dim V+W=4$.

As for a basis of $V+W$, you can take any basis of $\mathbf R^4$. You also can deduce from the bases of $V$ and $W$ a basis of $V+W$: just star from the basis in $V$, and join to this basis one of the vectors in the basis of $W$ which does not satisfy the equation of $V$.

For $V\cap  W$, write the matrix with rows the coefficients of the equations that define it, and row reduce this matrix to find it rank:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&1&1\\1&1&0&0\\0&0&1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&-2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus the system of equations has rank $3$, and this rank is the *codimension* of $V\cap W$. In other words $\dim V\cap W=1$.

We may proceed further to obtain the *reduced echelon form* of the matrix to  obtain a basis of $V\cap W$:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\0&1&1&1\\0&0&1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\0&1&0&3\\0&0&1&-2
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&-3\\0&1&0&3\\0&0&1&-2
\end{bmatrix}. $$
A basis of   $V\cap  W$ is the last column of the reduced matrix: 
$$\begin{bmatrix}-3\\3\\-2
\end{bmatrix}.$$